# NuxtJS: Using async/await with mounted() and $nextTick()?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

How can I use async/await here? My below code did not work because `await` is outside the `async`function according to my console message.

```
  async mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
      this.anno = await window.Annotorious.init({
        image: this.photo.id
      })
      await this.setAuthorInfo()
      this.anno.setVisible(false)
      setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 500)
    })
```

Comment: Put `nextTick` in a method and wait for resolve

Comment: Do you have a code sample? I'll make it as answer.

Comment: do `this.$nextTick(async () => {` but you dont need the `this.$nextTick` anyway

Comment: @LawrenceCherone:  Why do you say I don't need $nextTick? I am trying to do this: https://nuxtjs.org/guides/features/loading#programmatically-starting-the-loading-bar

Comment: without looking,internally the `this.$nuxt.$loading` plugin/component should/would not be in the component which is being rendered, so without it, it's going to start to show the loading plugin/component before the initial render of the plugin.. think of nextTick in mounted abit like a IIFE after onload gets fired, it doesn't make sense to load the component/render it then start to show a loading element. vue is fast and probably orders it in a way that it's not even noticeable.. try without it, if it doesn't work at all, put it back ;p besides the actual issue is putting async on the function

Comment: also you can do just `setTimeout(this.$nuxt.$loading.finish, 500)`

Answer (score 2):

Add `async` Before `()`:

```js
async mounted() {
  this.$nextTick(async () => {
    this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
    this.anno = await window.Annotorious.init({
      image: this.photo.id
    })
    await this.setAuthorInfo()
    this.anno.setVisible(false)
    setTimeout(() => this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(), 500)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example for `async mounted`

```
<template>
    <div v-if="testAsync">{{testAsync}}</div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        testAsync: "",
      }
    },

    async mounted() {
      let start = + new Date();
      this.testAsync= await this.testPromise();
      let finish = + new Date();
      console.log("here we wait ", finish - start, " ms for you");
    },

    methods:{
      async testPromise() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
          this.$nextTick(() => {
            this.$nuxt.$loading.start()
            setTimeout(() => { this.$nuxt.$loading.finish(); resolve('Hello');}, 5000);
          })
        });
      }
    }
</script>
```

Put `v-if` to be sure vue won't render template before `promise` resolved

Comment: reference https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function